# Basic facebook app integration doesn't work

Tags: facebook, web-applications

I'm trying to follow the JavaScript as well as build the most basic Facebook integration of a webpage and it is not working...  I don't understand why.

This is how it fails.
https://apps.facebook.com/fail-r-us/

I click App on Facebook and added a url: http://beta.brantleyswesternsupply.com/ .  I am expecting really only to see my url show up inside of facebook and I can't even get this to work.

I can't really find very much good documentation on this. I have followed a couple of websites that describe this but apparently the interface has changed from the time those websites were created.

Comment: Ok, I see that answer is different and based on this one.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841139/server-error405-http-verb-used-to-access-this-page-is-not-allowed

Answer (score 0):

Your domain is not **SSL** enabled; and to get your site on the facebook canvas it is mandatory to provide the **Secure Canvas URL**.

So, get the certification and fill-in the secure canvas url and your app will run.

And yes, do check that the **sandbox mode** is disabled in the app settings. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your help...unfortunately, that can't be the problem.  Check it now.  I switched it to http://www.salescart.net and https://www.salescart.net and it still doesn't work.  So now there is a secure and unsecure url.  I disabled sandbox mode...same thing.